# Have to define a function that can find the averages of multiple list of list in python

Tags: python, list, function

I have made list of list, now I want to define a function that can calculate the averages of each list. I have made a function, but it only works for the list that is on first index. How can I make it run for all lists

```
def final_list(x):
        average=list(map(int, final_list[x]))
        sum_list = sum(average)
        len_list = len(average)
        average_final = sum_list/len_list
```

Comment: As it stands your code will through an error. You are defining a function named `final_list`, however you are then trying to access the index of this function `final_list[x]` which is not possible. What is the input to `final_list`? Please provide more details.

Comment: Hey , okay so yes I have a nested list but I dont want the first list but averages of all other list in that nested list

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension to compute the average for each sublist

```
def average(x):
    return sum(x) / len(x)

def final_list(lists):
    return [average(x) for x in lists]
```

Answer (score 0):

hey you mean somthing like this?

```py
import random

def array_avg(array):
    for lst in array:
        length = len(lst)
        average = sum(lst) / length
        print(f"list average = {average}")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    arr = [[c for c in range(1, random.randint(2, 10))] for i in range(5)]
    array_avg(arr)
```